How can I mock a final class variable in Dart for unit testing?
I'm working on a Dart project where I need to write unit tests for a class that uses a final class variable for making API calls. The class is structured like this:
class MyClass {
  final MyApi _api;

  MyClass(this._api);

  Future<void> myMethod() async {
    final response = await _api.getData();
    // Process the response
  }
}

The MyApi instance is initialized as a final class variable in the constructor, like this:
class MyApi {
  final Dio _dio;

  MyApi(this._dio);

  Future<Response> getData() async {
    return await _dio.get('https://example.com/data');
  }
}

I want to write unit tests for MyClass, but I'm facing a challenge because _api is a final class variable and I can't modify the actual code to inject a mock instance during testing.
Is there a way to mock _api for testing purposes without modifying the original code?

When you say that you can't modify the code, do you mean that you can't modify the interface or the implementation too?  If you can't modify MyClass at all, then there isn't much you can do.  However, it is very strange to write unit tests for a class that you do not control.

@jamesdlin I cannot modify MyClass at all.

You cannot mock a final class, unless you are creating the mock inside the same library where the final class is declared. (Which you shouldn't, because your production code shouldn't depend on the mock library.)

It's unclear what your actual problem is. Can you explain what you would like your code to look like and why that doesn't work right now?

In order to pass a mock instance of the MyApi class to MyClass, pass the mock instance through the MyClass() constructor.
Like this:
class MockMyApi implements MyApi {
  MockMyApi(this.expectedData);

  final String expectedData;

  @override
  Future<String> getData() async {
    return expectedData;
  }
}

void main() {
  test('MyClass test', () async {
    final mockApi = MockMyApi('Mock data');
    final myClass = MyClass(mockApi);

    /// Rest of the test
  });
}



